# Independent scrolling of content in remaining space

Tags: html, css

I want to be able to scroll the content of `pane1` and `pane2` independently in the remainder space in the layout as shown below.
So `header` shall always be visible and `content` should take up the remaining space. It's important that `pane1` and `pane2` can be scrolled independently, meaning that e.g. I can scroll `pane1` to the bottom while the top of `pane2` is still visible.

The solution shouldn't assume any fixed size elements.

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>Header</div>
      <div id='content'>
        <div id='pane1' style=" display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height:3000px; background: red">
          content 1 A<br>
          content 1 B<br>
          content 1 C<br>
        </div>
        <div id='pane2' style=" display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height:2000px; background: blue">
          content 2 A<br>
          content 2 B<br>
          content 2 C<br>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a fixed-height container around the panes, with an `overflow-y: auto;` like below. I realize you've mentioned you didn't want any fixed sizes, but you have to tell the browser some way what height the panes are, if you want them scrollable; wrapping the whole thing in another `div` rather than fixing the height of the `.pane-container` would work too. And, the height of the `.pane-container` could be anything; percentages, absolute values, etcetera.

```css
.pane-container {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div>Header</div>
      <div id='content'>
        <div class="pane-container">
          <div id='pane1' style=" display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height:3000px; background: red">
            content 1 A<br>
            content 1 B<br>
            content 1 C<br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pane-container">
          <div id='pane2' style=" display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; height:2000px; background: blue">
            content 2 A<br>
            content 2 B<br>
            content 2 C<br>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
var header = jQuery(".header").innerHeight();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var abc = "calc(100% - " +header+ "px)";
jQuery(".content").css("height", abc);
})
```

```css
    body,html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
    margin:0;
    }
    *{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    }
    .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .content {
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:flex-start;
    }
    div[class*="pane"] {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    }
    .pane1 div {
    height: 2000px;
    }
    .pane2 div {
    height: 1000px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="header">Header</div>
          <div class="content">
            <div class='pane1' style="background-color: blue;">
              <div>
              content 1 A<br>
              content 1 B<br>
              content 1 C<br>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pane2" style="background-color: brown;">
             <div>
              content 2 A<br>
              content 2 B<br>
              content 2 C<br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Well he wanted `pane2` to be scrollable too, and in your example, it's not.

Comment: Your solution also assumes the header is 100px. This is not realistic in my case. The content of the header can even change dynamically in my case.

Comment: @vrugtehagel if he increase content in pane2 it will be scrollable.

Comment: @Tin have a look now maybe its same as what you want

Answer (score 0):

After some fiddling around I found a solution that is pure CSS:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div style=" display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; ">
      <div>Header</div>
      <div id='container' style="flex-grow: 1; overflow: hidden; position: relative; ">
        <div id='content' style="position: absolute;top: 0;bottom: 0;">
          <div id='pane1' style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;height: 100%;background: red;overflow: scroll;">
          </div>
          <div id='pane2'  style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;height: 100%;background: blue;overflow: scroll;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```